# Using a placeholder as a tensorflow Variable (getting Error!)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to use a placeholder in my graph as a Variable (so I can later optimise something with respect to it), but I don't know the best way to do that. I've tried this:

`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,1])
x_as_variable = tf.Variable(x, validate_shape = False)`

but everytime I build my graph, I get an error when I try to add my loss function:
`train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(MSEloss)`

The error is:
ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.

Even if you're not familiar with the error entirely, I'd really appreciate it if you could guide me on how to build a replicate Variable which takes on the value of my placeholder.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste your full stack trace?

Comment: Sure, here's a link http://pastebin.com/h1GENEsq

Comment: seems like I can't do optimization on a non-static-sized Variable

Comment: yes, you may have to give a complete shape to the placeholder.

Answer (score 4):

As you've noticed, TensorFlow optimizers (i.e. subclasses of [`tf.train.Optimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer)) operate on [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) objects because they need to be able to assign new values to those objects, and in TensorFlow only variables support an assign operation. If you use a [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder), there's nothing to update, because the value of a placeholder is immutable within each step.

So how do you optimize with respect to a fed-in value? I can think of two options:

1. Instead of feeding a `tf.placeholder()`, you could first assign a fed-in value to a variable and then optimize with respect to it:

   ```
   var = tf.Variable(...)
   set_var_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, ...)
   set_var_op = var.assign(set_var_placeholder)
   # ...
   train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(...).minimize(mse_loss, var_list=[var, ...])

   # ...
   initial_val = ...  # A NumPy array.
   sess.run(set_var_op, feed_dict={set_var_placeholder: initial_val})
   sess.run(train_op)
   updated_val = sess.run(var)
   ```
2. You could use the lower-level [`tf.gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#gradients) function to get the gradient of the loss with respect to a placeholder in a single step. You could then use that gradient in Python:

   ```
   var = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, ...)
   # ...
   mse_loss = ...
   var_grad, = tf.gradients(loss, [var])

   var_grad_val = sess.run(var_grad, feed_dict={var: ...})
   ```

---

PS. The code in your question, where you define a `tf.Variable(tf.placeholder(...), ...)` is just defining a variable whose **initial value** is fed by the placeholder. This probably isn't what you want, because the training op that the optimizer creates will only use the value assigned to the variable, and ignore whatever you feed to the placeholder (after the initialization step).

Comment: For 1), wouldn't the assign op be added automatically when you directly feed a placeholder into a variable? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L358

Comment: An assign op would be added, yes, but you'd have to remember to run `var.initializer` with a feed dict. It could work, but option 2 is probably better... especially if the shapes can change.

Comment: Ah, okay the problem here is that the Adam optimizer needs to create auxilliary variables, and to do that they need to be the same shape as the input. Right now it relies on the static shape because almost all variables have static shape (and it probably isn't easy to define the meaning of these auxilliary variables when the shape of the weights changes). Can you try option 2, or is there some reason it doesn't work for you?